# Json search function

Tags: python, json

I am trying to make a search function where I get a users' `input` and then it searches through my `config.json` to see if there's an entry with the same name, if yes it prints the value if not then `pass`

```
recipient_finder = input("Recipient: ")
for receiver in config['email_list']:
    if receiver == recipient_finder:
        print([recipient_finder])
```

this is in my `config.json`

```
  "email_list": {
    "mediamarkt": "contact@mediamarkt.nl",
    "lenovo": "consumerts@lenovo.com",
    "godaddy": "hq@godaddy.com",
    "stackoverflow": "legal@stackoverflow.com"
    }
```

The issue is that I am not getting an actual email from the search rather a key (so i won't get hq@godaddy.com but just godaddy)

Comment: what is issue here ?

Comment: Are you searching for the keys or the values in the dictionary? `receiver` is looping over the keys.

Comment: There's no need for a loop, just `if receiver in config['email_list']:`

Comment: What I need is the program to look through the strings, and then give the value

Comment: So if the user types `lenovo` it should print `consumerts@lenovo.com`?

Comment: yes that's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the user input is a key in the dictionary. If it is, print the corresponding value.

```
if receiver in config['email_list']:
    print(config['email_list'][receiver]
else:
    print("Not found")
```

Comment: This worked, can't accept your answer yet but will asap.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below:

```
recipient_finder = input("Recipient: ")
for receiver in config['email_list']:
    if receiver == recipient_finder:
        print(config['email_list'][recipient_finder])
```

OR

```
if recipient_finder in config['email_list']:
    print(config['email_list'][recipient_finder])
```